# Using Excel to return a value based on 3 variables

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table that consists of multiple columns, and rows that contain the data. I want it to return a value based on multiply variables.

The headings are say:
       Client A,       Client B,      Client C,     Client D, with each Client having two options, Opt1 Opt2, across the columns, with data held in rows below (A3-A100)

I want to write a formula that will return the value in the table based on the 3 chosen variables - e.g. Row E, Client B, Opt 2, returns the value in the corresponding cell

I have tried using INDEX Match but it's not working and wondering if a simple VBA code would be a better solution.

Thanks in anticipation.

Comment: A picture is worth a 1000 words, please mock up the data and expected outcome in tabular form.  It will make it easier for us to help you without unneeded time spent thinking along a different track.

Comment: Dept      Product  Sales  Research  Development   
Section A B         A B           A B          A B 
          
Price          
10         1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
15         2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11
20         3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12
25         4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13
30         5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14
35         6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15
40         7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16
45         8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17
50         9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18
          
          
Input Dept Sales         
Input Section B         
Input Price 35         
Output

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, but messy, to do this in formulas if your reference array is sorted appropriately.

Otherwise a VBA function is indeed probably your best bet:

```
Function Match3(LookupZone As Range, _
            Seek1 As Variant, Seek2 As Variant, Seek3 As Variant, _
            RefCol1 As Long, RefCol2 As Long, RefCol3 As Long, _
            ReturnCol As Long) _
        As Variant

Dim ARow As Long

Match3 = CVErr(xlErrNA)
If RefCol1 > LookupZone.Columns.Count Then Exit Function
If RefCol2 > LookupZone.Columns.Count Then Exit Function
If RefCol3 > LookupZone.Columns.Count Then Exit Function
If ReturnCol > LookupZone.Columns.Count Then Exit Function
'                
For ARow = 1 To LookupZone.Rows.Count
    If LookupZone(ARow, RefCol1).Value = Seek1 _
        And LookupZone(ARow, RefCol2).Value = Seek2 _
        And LookupZone(ARow, RefCol3).Value = Seek3 _
            Then
        Match3 = LookupZone(ARow, ReturnCol).Value
        Exit Function
    End If
Next ARow

End Function
```

Then you can use this in your spreadsheet as required.